# ExpressJS application not working after deployment (502 error )

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose, render.com

I'm working on a nodejs (expressJS) application with monogdb. it working fine without any errors and issues on my local environment. but after deployment the application is not loading and showing different error from different platform.

I have used 2 different services for this application and they both showing different error after visiting hosted application

1. render
   [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mPc8g.png)
2. cyclic
   [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LU4kl.png)

same application working totally fine on my local environment.
you can check out my git repo ([link](https://github.com/Harshkhanagwal/blogapp)) for source code

here's the application on my local environment:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/emugV.png)

Comment: Everything is uploaded to a third-party website and the link is attached to the question which leads other developers to doubt opening another third-party website..